# SDK para leitura de código de cheque CMC7

Tags: ios

Preciso desenvolver uma aplicação para iPhone e iPad que faça leitura de código de barra de cheque ([CMC7](http://www.scpc-online.com.br/web2tpc/scpc/help/cmc7.htm) <sup><sub>[cópia](https://web.archive.org/web/20140313001334/http://www.scpc-online.com.br/web2tpc/scpc/help/cmc7.htm)</sub></sup>), mas estou encontrando dificuldades para achar uma SDK free, existe algum?

Comment: Luis, coloquei um link de referência para o CMC7, por favor, fique a vontade para modificar ou excluir se não achar relevante.

Comment: @brasofilo O link está quebrado para mim, confirma isto?

Comment: @Otávio: sim, confirmado, adicionei um mirror.